# Как в PyCharm отключить создание виртуального окружения для каждого проекта?

Tags: python, pycharm

Пока что пользуюсь VSCode с расширением Python от Microsoft, но почему-то не всегда появляются подсказки о том, какие методы и свойства есть у переменной.

Решил попробовать PyCharm. Хочу просто открыть его редактор, создать пустой .py файл и писать код с функционалом PyCharm'а, но там при каждом запуске надо создавать проект, либо выбрать уже готовый файл/проект. При создании проекта обязательно создается виртуальное окружение, на моем компе это не быстро.

Как отключить принудительное создание виртуального окружения при создании проекта? Чтобы он автоматически использовал основной интерпритатор Python в системе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это возможно сделать и после создания проекта:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, затем в левом столбце выберите **«Project: Имя»**, и под ним выберите **«Project Interpreter»**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем вправо вверху нажмите на колесико:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и выберите `«Add...»`.

Вы получите окно, в котором выберите - *это серьезно для вас* - `«System Interpreter»`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и в случае необходимости вправо вверху выберите соответствующий интерпретатор Питона.